# Introduction into first order logic verification

Tags: reference-request, logic, formal-methods, sat-solvers, software-verification

I am trying to teach myself different approaches to software verification. I have read some articles. As far as I learned, propositional logic with temporal generally uses model checking with SAT solvers (in ongoing - reactive systems), but what about first order Logic with temporal? Does it use theorem provers? Or can it also use SAT?

Any pointers to books or articles for beginners in this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: First of all welcome to CS:SE. While I am not an expert at this you seem to be grabbing at several topics at once leaving lots of holes. Don't worry; I do it all the time. Take a look at [Software verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_verification) then [Formal verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) then [Model checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking) and [Formal Software Verification: Model Checking and Theorem Proving](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~piotr/Courses/662/Reading/ESL-TIK-00214.pdf)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First order logic is undecidable, so SAT solving does not really help. That said, techniques exist for bounded model checking of first order formulas. This means that only a fixed number of objects can be considered when trying to determine whether the formula is true or false. Clearly, this is not complete, but if a counter-example is found, then it truly is a counter-example.

The tool [Alloy](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/) is one tool that allows models to be described in first-order logic (though the surface syntax is based on relationally described models) and uses bounded model checking to find solutions. A SAT solver is used under the hood. One alloy extension allows models with a temporal character, though technically it does not support temporal logic.

If you wish to explore further, for example, to verify program correctness, then you can look at program verification tools. These are generally based on Hoare logic (for reasoning about pre- and post-conditions), possibly extended with Separation logic (for reasoning about heaps). These logics are generally undecidable, so a certain amount of interaction between the human and the verification tool is required.
Some example tools are:

- [Verifast](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~bart.jacobs/verifast/)
- [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/)

Answer (score 11):

After reading your question the only way I could see and had enough knowledge to tie the topics together was to give a hi-level set of articles that drill down from software verification ending up with trying to unite model checking and theorem proving. Hopefully my comment did that:

Take a look at [Software verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_verification)  then [Formal verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) then [Model checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking)  and [Formal Software Verification: Model Checking and Theorem Proving](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~piotr/Courses/662/Reading/ESL-TIK-00214.pdf)

Dave has given a good answer for which I cannot do much more justice to the first part of the question than Dave had done, since I am also new to this.

Since this is your first question at an [SE](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) site, the reason I did not give an answer but a comment is because here an answer cannot be just a set of links, but must give a written answer and use links in support of the answer; thus a comment instead of an answer.

With regards to:

> Any pointers to books or articles for beginners in this matter is much
>   appreciated.

Books I would suggest and use are:

- [Logic in Computer Science - Modelling and Reasoning about Systems 2nd Ed. by Huth and Ryan](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/249810058) This introduces logic and moves up to model checking, but doesn't go into theorem proving. So this should cover all of your basic questions related to logic and model checking.
- [Principles of model checking by Baier and Katoen](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/759831080) I just started reading this one, and it is much better than reading lots of papers and trying to see how they all fit together. This is one of the most, if not the most recommended book on the subject of model checking. It should answer your more advanced questions on model checking.
- [Temporal logic and state systems by Kroger and Merz](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/261325420) I often like to have books by different authors when self-learning a subject. This one is to complement/round out "Principles of model checking"
- [Handbook of practical logic and automated reasoning by Harrison](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/734055415) Being a programmer I can't recommend this book enough. The book starts off with introducing logic and moves all the way through the point of creating the kernel for a theorem prover based on the work of [HOL Light](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/). Just to highlight that the book uses working OCaml code, explains the theorems in terms I find friendly and gives you what you need to know but not so much that you can't make the connection or feel like you are running down side tracks. If is a very focused book on going from logic to a specific type of theorem prover.
- [How to prove it : a structured approach by Velleman](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/62084309) To get into the [Proof assistants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) for theorem proving you will need to live and sleep theorems.
- [A Introduction to Proofs and the Mathematical Vernacular by Day](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/day/ProofsBook/IPaMV.pdf) This is a free book that not only complements "How to prove it", it goes beyond it in sum regards. I would not be surprised to see this one become popular.

At present I cannot expand more on theorem proving because I am still learning the pro/cons and differences of each one, but the ones I am focusing in are

- [HOL Light](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/) because of the [book](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/734055415) by John Harrison.
- [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/) because it is based on [Calculus of constructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions)
- [Isabelle](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/) because it is based on higher-order unification.

  These proof assistants also typically have book(s), are current, popular, open-source, maintained, and have active support communities.

Note: I used worldcat.org to reference the books, but you can review them using Amazon's look inside feature.

Comment: To avoid lots of edits to the answer, I will drop added info as comments and then in the future roll them up into the answer. For trying to sort out the many similarities and differences between proof assistants. Google for Freek Wiedijk; I find his papers to be quite useful.

Comment: Many many thanks for your detailed and thorough answer. For adding your comments on books and providing a link to the free book. Again, I can't thank you enough :-)